# Error upgrading Server 2019 Evaluation to full

Tags: dism, windows-server-2019

I have downloaded the iso of Windows Server 2019 from the evaluation center and installed the standard core edition (in a VM on Hyper-V Server 2019). I now want to upgrade this to the standard core non-evaluation edition using a SB OEM key. I therefor used the command:

```
dism /online /Set-Edition:ServerStandardCor /ProductKey:XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX /AcceptEula
```

I then get the error 1168. [Here](https://gist.github.com/fel5/d834e0fcf1ec9cd4edd5841728e23851) is the dism log (I removed the key).

Strangely, `dism /online /Get-TargetEditions` gets me only `ServerDatacenterCor` as target edition. 
`dism /online /Get-CurrentEdition` returns `ServerStandardEvalCor` as current edition.

Comment: I wasn't aware you could even change the edition on those virtual machines.  By "SB" you mean small business?  I assume you have the proper infrastructure (i.e. KMS) in place to activate Windows Server 2019?

Comment: By SB i mean system builder version

Comment: According to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/supported-upgrade-paths) an upgrade should be possible. I have no activation infrastructure, I just want to use an OEM key i bought.

Comment: I have never heard of a system builder license for Window Server.  Is this key considered to be a Retail key.  However, based on the output of `/Get-TargetEditions`, your Windows Server installation can only be changed to `Windows Server 2019 Datacenter` based on the description of that command.

Comment: I think SB is a european thing, it's basically an OEM version that you can just normally buy. This is officially possible, it's not some shady half legal thing.

Comment: I don't believe you can use Windows Server 2019 with having a KMS.  The KMS can be itself Windows Server does not activate in the same way as Windows 10 does.  I suspect you will have to simply install what you purchased instead of trying to upgrade from an evaluation installation.  The documentation specifically indicates a Retail license.  The error you are getting indicates the license isn't eligible to be used.

Comment: Isn't KMS for volume licensing?

Comment: If i use `dism /online /get-targeteditions` on 2019 Standard Eval non-core, i get Server Standard as a possible target edition. Maybe its just not possible on core.